# How to send email from sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have one column called status
    Status
      1
      2
      3
      4
      2
    In status column have id,if the status id is 2 then i nees to send mail so please help me out from this problem.

Comment: what did you try so far? what is your problem?

Comment: I"m voting to close as too broad, but here is a place to start:  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/ and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191207(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: If you google "how to send email from sql" you will find lots of examples.

Comment: @Tab Alleman "have u red my explaination?? "

Answer (score 1):

When you update the status id, just check the current id afterwards. If the id is 2 send an email.

Example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE status SET id = '2' WHERE id = '1'");

//here u updated the status id. now check the new one

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Status WHERE whatever = 'whatsever'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $newid = $result['id'];
}
//now you have the new id. Test if its "2" and if true, send an email
if($newid == 2){
   //Send mailstuff here
}
```

Comment: My reading of the question is that OP wants to send directly from sqlserver (so not MySql or PHP)

Comment: @HansKesting you cannot send an email from a Mysql Server. I think the only method is my method above.

Comment: I meant "sqlserver" as in "Microsoft Sql Server" - see the `sql-server` tag.